# html unwanted space between divs in IE but not in chrome

Tags: css, html, space

thanks for reading this.

I am currently struggling with this website http://ukshinwakai.org/uks/ in IE I get space between footer and header. Could some one tell me how to fix this please!?

This is the html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="description" content="Welcome to United Kingdom Shinwakai official website" >
<meta name="keywords" content="Shinwakai, UK Shinwakai, Jack Poole, Aikido, Marill Poole, 7th Dan Aikido, Yoshinkan, Aikido Buckinghamshire" >
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" >
<meta name="author" content="Adam Lisik Web Design" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>Home Page UK Shinwakai</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersubs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("ul.sf-menu").supersubs({ 
            minWidth:    5,  
            maxWidth:    17,
            extraWidth:  1   
        }).superfish();
    }); 
//]]>
</script>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/banner.gif" alt="UK Shinwakai" width="991" height="203" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="bread">
        <p>You are here: <a href="index.php">Home</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical">
                <li class="current"><span class="style3"><a href="index.php">Home</a></span></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">About the Association</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="ukshistory.php">Association History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="membership.php">Membership of the Association</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Heads of Shinwakai</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="jack.php">Sensei Jack Poole</a></li>
                                <li><a href="marill.php">Sensei Marill Poole</a></li>
                                <li><a href="les.php">Sensei Les White</a></li>
                                <li><a href="roy.php">Sensei Roy Sheppard</a></li>
                                <li><a href="john.php">Sensei John Jenkin</a></li>
                                <li><a href="keith.php">Sensei Keith Holland</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Who We Are!</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="equal.php">Equal Opportunities</a></li>
                                <li><a href="constitution.php">Constitution</a></li>
                                <li><a href="children.php">Children in Aikido</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Association Dojos</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Koshinkan Aikido Society</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="k_brix.php">Brixham Dojo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="k_sutton.php">Sutton Dojo</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Kurai Aikido</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="k_chelms.php">Chelmsford Dojo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="k_yeading.php">Yeading Dojo</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">UK Shinwakai Aikido</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="beaconsfield.php">Beaconsfield Dojo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="huddersfield.php">West Yorkshire Dojos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="maidenhead.php">Maidenhead Dojo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="manjuji.php">Manju-ji Dojo</a></li><li><a href="sano.php">Sano Dojo</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sanobudokan.php">Sano Budokan Dojo</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Traditional Aikido Ryu</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="ashford.php">Ashford Dojo</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            <li class="style3"><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="uknews.php">Association News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="babnews.php">BAB News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="othernews.php">BBC News &amp; Weather</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact the Association</a></li>
            <li><a href="photo.php">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.php">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.ukshinwakaiaikido.org.uk">To UK Shinwaikai Aikido</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pagecontent">
         <?php include 'edit/index/index.php';?>
        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<a class="addthis_button" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;username=ukshinw1"><img src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-en.gif" width="125" height="16" alt="Bookmark and Share" class="c2" /></a> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};
//]]>
</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=ukshinw1">
</script> <!-- AddThis Button END --></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; ukshinwakai.org&#44 ukshinwakaiassociation.org.uk &amp; ukshinwakaiaikido.org.uk. All Rights Reserved.
        <a href="http://www.adamlisik.co.uk">Web Design Huddersfield</a>    </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS
http://ukshinwakai.org/uks/style.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing's first, add doctype (on top of the code)

http://validator.w3.org/docs/help.html#faq-doctype

Comment: +1 This is correct. IE is rendering the page in [_Quirks mode_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Adding the correct DOCTYPE will fix the problem. It never hurts to make sure the the markup is valid as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `*{margin:0, border:0}` and the proper DOCTYPE.